# XML to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I am looking for a JavaScript library that parses an XML string and converts it to a JavaScript object. What are some good ones?

Answer (score 34):

The following function parses XML and returns a JavaScript object with a scheme that corresponds to the XML. XML siblings w/ the same name are collapsed into arrays. nodes with names that can be found in the `arrayTags` parameter (array of tag name strings) always yield arrays even in case of only one tag occurrence. `arrayTags` can be omitted. Text nodes with only spaces are discarded.

```
function parseXml(xml, arrayTags) {
    let dom = null;
    if (window.DOMParser) dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        dom.async = false;
        if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) throw dom.parseError.reason + " " + dom.parseError.srcText;
    }
    else throw new Error("cannot parse xml string!");

    function parseNode(xmlNode, result) {
        if (xmlNode.nodeName == "#text") {
            let v = xmlNode.nodeValue;
            if (v.trim()) result['#text'] = v;
            return;
        }

        let jsonNode = {},
            existing = result[xmlNode.nodeName];
        if (existing) {
            if (!Array.isArray(existing)) result[xmlNode.nodeName] = [existing, jsonNode];
            else result[xmlNode.nodeName].push(jsonNode);
        }
        else {
            if (arrayTags && arrayTags.indexOf(xmlNode.nodeName) != -1) result[xmlNode.nodeName] = [jsonNode];
            else result[xmlNode.nodeName] = jsonNode;
        }

        if (xmlNode.attributes) for (let attribute of xmlNode.attributes) jsonNode[attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;

        for (let node of xmlNode.childNodes) parseNode(node, jsonNode);
    }

    let result = {};
    for (let node of dom.childNodes) parseNode(node, result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Maylow , Welcome to SO, It will be more helpful if you can provide a small description along with your answers,

Comment: Also take a look to my improvement down there

Comment: @MaylowHayes this produces a Script error when used in IE11. Any ideas?

Comment: Text node is empty for every node :(

Comment: I had to modify this to make it work, as I was trying to nest this in my existing code and it didn't like the function in a function. 

What I did was break all the nested functions out into the main thread (to define them) and then called them on my nodes that I wanted to parse (I already had done the xml.getElementsByTag('tag-name') to get them nodes I wanted.

E.g. 
function parseNode(xmlNode, result) { .... }
let nodes = Array.from(XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName('tag-name'));
nodes.forEach(node => {
   let nodeResult = {}
   parseNode(node, nodeResult)
   console.log(nodeResult)
})

Comment: i like this approach. use the build-in XML Parser and then modify the output to be easier to work with

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice xml2json and json2xml converter:

- http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

  - Related tutorial: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html

Here's another one:

- http://www.kawa.net/works/js/xml/objtree-e.html

Depending on your needs, you might be able to use a standard parser (see http://www.w3schools.com/XML/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest2) and xpath (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) - here's an example:

- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5272

and a few nice tutorials:

- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/17/xpath-in-javascript-part-1/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript

Comment: The problem with Goessner's library is that it returns a JSON string. You'll end up converting an XML string to a JSON string, which you'll then have to parse _again_ to get an actual Javascript object. It would work, but there is probably a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Going straight to the point (**using [node-xml2json](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json)**):

```sh
npm install xml2json
```

Then, use it:

```js
const parser = require('xml2json');

const obj = parser.toJson(xml, { object: true });
```

---

#### Example:

```js
const parser = require('xml2json');

const xml = '<root><person><name>Bob Dylan</name></person></root>';

const obj = parser.toJson(xml, { object: true });
const { person } = obj.root;
person.name; // Bob Dylan
```

You can also convert from JSON to XML, and [much more](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a simple Typescript version that didn't create additional #text objects and also disregarded attributes. If that's what you need, here's the code:

```
export class DomFuncs {

    static parseNode = (node: Node) => {    
        const childNodes = node.childNodes;
        if (childNodes.length === 0) {
            return node.nodeValue;
        } else if (childNodes.length === 1 && childNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        } else {
            const obj = {};
            childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
                const childName = childNode.nodeName;
                const childValue = obj[childName];
                if (childValue !== undefined) {
                    if (Array.isArray(childValue)) {
                        childValue.push(DomFuncs.parseNode(childNode));
                    } else {
                        obj[childName] = [childValue, DomFuncs.parseNode(childNode)];
                    }
                } else {
                    obj[childName] = DomFuncs.parseNode(childNode);
                }
            });
            return obj;
        }
    };

    static xml2obj = (str: string) => {
        const dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml')
        const result = {[dom.nodeName]: DomFuncs.parseNode(dom)};
        return result;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
DomFuncs.xml2obj(xmlString);
```

This script currently disregards XML attributes since my converted object didn't require them. If you need that, let me know and I could update the code.

Answer (score 0):

The xml2json javascript file from https://bitbucket.org/surenrao/xml2json is all you need to do this.

Here's the download link for quick download: https://bitbucket.org/surenrao/xml2json/get/0e0989dfe48e.zip

Once included in your project, here's some sample code to get you started:

```
var xmlStr = "<root><person><name>Bob Dylan</name></person></root>";
var jsObj = X2J.parseXml(xmlStr);
var result = jsObj[0].root[0].person[0].name[0].jValue; //Bob Dylan
```