# selecting data from xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i want to select just two items from xml file  with itemno and quantity that have less prices.can anybody help me how to do this in javascript.

items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <itemno>1</itemno>
        <unitprice>99</unitprice>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemno>2</itemno>
        <unitprice>80</unitprice>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemno>3</itemno>
        <unitprice>120</unitprice>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </item>
</items>
```

javascript:

```
var xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.load("items.xml");
var items=xmlDoc.documentElement;
var item = itemss.childNodes(0);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm feeling rather case-sensitive today.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object

Comment: @Adam Bergmark i am not using JSON in this example

Comment: What do you mean by "associative array" then? The term doesn't exist in js.

Comment: @Adam Bergmark ok.i have used associative array and ksort for this example in php , which works correctly but now i want to do this in javascript...

Comment: sort all items by `unitprice`, then return the first two. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gz5gK/1) with jQuery.

Comment: @bina: Do you realize that your code ***only works in IE***? Other browsers do not have ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

All of the basic DOM methods also work for XML:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

You can find all items using

```
items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');
```

For each item, one of the children is the cost node:

```
priceNode = item.childNodes[1];
```

(Or you could go through the childnodes, looking for the one with `nodeName` equal to "UNITPRICE")

Looking for the content of the node is trickier, since IE and FF support different methods:

```
priceStr =  priceStr.textContent || priceNode.innerText;
```

Finally, to convert a string into a number:

```
price = parseInt(priceStr, 10);
```

---

By the way, your way of building a XML document with ActiveX is IE specific. You should definitely look into using some sort of Javascript library (such as Jquery or Dojo) to smooth this and other things out.