# How to read this DOM object element elegantly without using jQuery find()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

I got some xml data, parsed it into a dom object so i can search and get values using jQuery.

Something like this:

```
<field>
    <name>Jesus</name>
    <group>God</group>
    <blah>Hello World</blah>
</field>
```

In my js, I used an `each()` to loop through the field:

```
data.find('field').each(function() {
    $(this).find("group").text();
}
```

I could use `find()` to fetch each field and content, but I don't want to use find as it could get expensive. I looked through the jQuery API i don't think i there is a function that could let me do something like "`getElement('name')`" or `children('name')` or `next('name')`, etc...

I don't want to use index either such as `$(this)[0].childNodes[0]` due to readability and potential future changes.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not to use the power of selector `$('field > name', data)`?

Comment: whether `data` is the `field` element? also `find` is not a problem if you are not dealing with a structure with 10s of thousands of elements

Comment: Or use JSON and avoid the lookups! What you want is basically what JSON offers.

Comment: I did considered using javascript object and json. Using jsobj i will have to write my own code to loop through the items, in my example the XML data is over simplified, but there are more elements in there. Using json is not any better either, some of the code could become hardcode and if structure changes then the code need to be update... using jQuery, i don't don't have to deal with the search functions. I mostly want a solution for the "last leg" of the search after it found the `<field>`. Even if structure changes, using the find would still find what i need with jQuery.

Comment: I saw one of the example that converts XML into js object, tried it, and is a lot of hassle to convert it, not to mention it has limitation and actually took more time than running `$.parseXML()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an answer that doesn't use jQuery at all! How's that?

Your problem seems to be searching through the XML structure. So you converted it to a DOM tree, but now you're worried about the performance issues of traversing the tree.

The solution is simple: don't convert your XML to HTML, convert it to a JavaScript object literal, and work with that. It'll be the most simple AND the most efficient. For reference to convert XML to an object literal: [XML to JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object)

Now you are free to use all the tools JavaScript offers to work with your data, and you avoid any jQuery/DOM efficiency problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
  


    function alertit(jqueryObject) {
      if (jqueryObject.length === 0) return;

      jqueryObject.each(function() {
          alert(this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
      });

      alertit(jqueryObject.children());
    }

    alertit($(xml));
```

Answer (score 0):

also try this

```
var xmlData = "<field><name>Jesus</name><group>God</group><blah>Hello World</blah></field>";
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = $.parseXML(xmlData);
    $(data).each(function (i, node) {
        alert($(node).text());
    });
});
```