# Regular expression to match google calendar event feed dates

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have been trying to match various dates from a google calendar xml feed in JavaScript but I am failing miserably.

Currently I have this regular expression:

```
\s(.*)\s
```

Here are some of the examples of strings (each code block is a string) in which I need to get matches (note the slashes and newlines):

string 1:

```
When: Thu Jan 9, 2014 1:50pm to 2:45pm 
GMT&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;br /&gt;Where: Hall A
&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed</content>
```

string 2:

```
When: Mon Jan 4, 2014&lt;br /&gt;


&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed</content>
```

string 3:

```
When: Mon Oct 27, 2013 to Fri Nov 1, 2013 
&lt;br /&gt;


&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed</content>
```

string 4:

```
When: Tue Oct 15, 2013 3:30pm to 7:30pm 
BST&lt;br /&gt;


&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed
&lt;br /&gt;Event Description: Please complete a booking.&amp;#39;s teacher.</content>
```

string 5:

```
When: Mon Apr 21, 2014 to Fri Apr 25, 2014 
&lt;br /&gt;


&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed</content>
```

So I want to only match either date in the format "Day Mon dd, year" or "Day Mon dd, year time". I do not want the part after that. I don't need to have the "to" part.

So if a date with time exists, it should match that, if time does not exist then it should match just the date.

I am very new to regex and don't really know how to go about this. I plan to pick up a book on it and learn it properly but I have to solve this quickly.

If anyone could help me out I would be very thankful.

Comment: if they are sending you XML...please use an XML parser not RegEx, if you want to specify a backend language I could assist further or you could use JavaScript XML parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried to use the parser, and I now got a JSON object. I tried to print out the object.feed.entry.summary value and I got this:
When: Thu 9 Jan 2014 13:45 to 14:45&nbsp;
GMT<br>

<br>Where: Art Room
<br>Event Status: confirmed

As you can see its still not just a date. Maybe I just don't know how to get the date value out of the object. The problem is I am trying not to post the actual feed here in the public. Might make it difficult for you to see how the actual xml looks.

Comment: Correct without the actual feed or a demo feed I can't help you parse an object.  However, since it is a JS object simply use the `.` formatted on your object in Console to see what is on it.  Chrome > Developer Tools > console > `object` it will show you everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are new to RegExp, let me tell you that there are two ways of using regex pattern.

1. using `new RegExp('pattern-here')`
2. using javascript syntax `/pattern-here/flags`

   second one is easy :)

The answer is

```
var regex = /(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}\s([0-9][0-2]|[0-9]):([0-6][0-9]|[0-6]{2})(pm|am)|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}/g
```

This does what you asked for.

The answer from abc123 doesn't match time and also, it matches illegal dates like

```
Hel Som 99, 9999
```

But mine doesn't.

To use it :

```
var matchDateRegex= /(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}\s([0-9][0-2]|[0-9]):([0-6][0-9]|[0-6]{2})(pm|am)|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}/gm;

var s="some string with date Mon Jan 22, 2013 some thing Mon Jan 22, 2013 1:50pm";
var dates= s.match(matchDateRegex);
```

This will return an array of matched dates which is stored in `dates` variable.

Now you can access the dates by their index.

**Note:** If you want to use just the pattern without *javascript syntax*, then remove first
character and the last three characters('/' and '/gm') but then you'll need to do

```
var regex=new RegExp('(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}\s([0-9][0-2]|[0-9]):([0-6][0-9]|[0-6]{2})(pm|am)|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s\d{4}','gm');
```

Mark it as **answer** if it helps. *(I'm sure it will)*

Comment: @alwaysStuck, here is a tip. Using new XMLSerializer().serializeToString() method, you can convert it to string and then use my regex to do what u want. The reason for why i am not commenting on your post is that I don't have enough reputations :)

Comment: I think that it's a bit of a stretch to say that "it matches illegal dates like `Hel Som 99, 9999` But mine doesn't.". Yours match `Thu Feb 31, 2014` which is an illegal date.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick Answer:

**[Regex:](http://regex101.com/r/wW8tV7)**

```
When: ([\w]{3}) ([\w]{3}) ([\d]{1,2}), ([\d]{4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IuqmYojpCWPLmx9Y)

**Regex Explained**

```
/When: ([\w]{3}) ([\w]{3}) ([\d]{1,2}), ([\d]{4})/
    When:  matches the characters When:  literally (case sensitive)
    1st Capturing group ([\w]{3})
        [\w]{3} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Exactly 3 times
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    matches the character   literally
    2nd Capturing group ([\w]{3})
        [\w]{3} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Exactly 3 times
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    matches the character   literally
    3rd Capturing group ([\d]{1,2})
        [\d]{1,2} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \d match a digit [0-9]
    ,  matches the characters ,  literally
    4th Capturing group ([\d]{4})
        [\d]{4} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Exactly 4 times
            \d match a digit [0-9]
```

***Note:*** if they are sending you XML...please use an XML parser not RegEx, if you want to specify a backend language I could assist further or you could use JavaScript XML parsing [XML to JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object)