# How to convert XML into Javascript object using Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, xml, javascript-objects

I have an XML that I need to convert to corresponding Javascript Object using Javascript and vice versa ?

Is there any known library available for this?

If not, please help with creating such a function for conversion.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As part of the community rules we don't welcome questions that ask recommendations for tools/libraries. That said, I've been using "fast-xml-parser" and happy with it so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object