# How to display data from XML URL to Javascript variable that will show on Highcharts Column?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new in c# web programming and i want to display the data from MySQL Server to Javascript variable to be shown in my Highchart Column. Is there anyway to display my result from Mysql to my javascript of Highchart Column?

```
line 2738-2802

<script type="text/javascript">


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


    document.addEventListener(function () {
        var requestData = $("ORT").val();
        var resultElemet = $('#testin');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:37590/Get_OGSData',
            method: 'get',
            data: { q: requestData },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                resultElement.html(data.SampleModel[0].main);
            }
        });
    });

    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('testing123', {


chart: {
    type: 'bar',

},
title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['1401-1402', '2015-2016', '2016-2017', '2017-2018', '2018-2019']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
    shared: true
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'BCT',
    data: [{
        id: 'testin',
    y:
    }, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'SHS',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'PBCT',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
});
})
```

I'm still confuse on how will i display the XML data to variable in javascript.

and also is there any difference in XML File and XML Data?

Comment: Do you use ajax to fetch your data (perhaps this example will be helpful for you: https://jsfiddle.net/541d08ea/)? Could you show your XML data?

Comment: yes.. but i'm still confuse how it works :(

Comment: You can convert xml to js object using these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object or one of libraries like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7up0428w/. Now, what do you want to present on the chart?

Comment: thank you for the response bro, i want to display on the chart the STRM as a label and the OGS(On Going Students) as the # of data under STRM("School Term")

Comment: is there any difference between the XML File that was created on solution explorer and the XML URL that comes from Controllers.CS?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know.