# Parse xml output from javascript method in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, soapui

I quite new to xml & javascript. I have written an method in js which returns the output in below format when invoked through soapUI. Am trying to call the same function from javascript. How can I parse the output?

I tried below code, but didn't work.

```
var tmp = interactionProposeOffers(offerEnvironment + "|" + offerSpace, recipientId, 1, xml, 0 , "", "" , "" , "" , "" , true);
var res = new XML(tmp.toXMLString());
```

Soap Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <urn:ProposeResponse xmlns:urn="urn:nms:interaction">
         <interactionId xsi:type="xsd:string">0</interactionId>
         <propositions xsi:type="ns:Element" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml">
            <propositions>
               <proposition id="43030" offer-id="11074076" offerSpace-id="7652687" weight="1" rank="1" prodOffer="">
                  <view>
                     <messageId>123</messageId>
                     <messageType>ABC</messageType>
                  </view>
               </proposition>
            </propositions>
         </propositions>
         <uuid/>
      </urn:ProposeResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the modern APIs usually return output in the format set in the Accept header, so if you set it to application/json, you might get the output in an easy to use format (JavaScript Object Notation = json).

If that is not an option, you might try DOMParser (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) although it feels difficult to use. One thinking outside the box solution would be to use jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). It also parses an XML string, but gives you a very simple to use API for finding elements and getting the values of content or of their attributes.

Clearly this question has been asked before. Here is an example: [XML to JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object)