# convert xml node into a typescript defined type

Tags: xml, typescript, serialization

I would like to convert an xml response into a typescript object. This is what I have done :

```
enum status {
    Pending = 1,
    Rejected = 5,
    Validated = 6
}
type Request = {
    totalInDays: number;
    status: string;    
}

const response = '<ns1:Request> 
    <ns1:totalInDays>0.5</ns1:totalInDays>
    <ns1:status>1</ns1:durationInDays>
    <ns1:startDate>22/07/2019</ns1:startDate>
    <ns1:endDate>22/07/2019</ns1:endDate>
</ns1:Request>'

const object = response as Request // this is not working
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the XML and turn it into an Object. 
The `response` object is currently of type `string`. With the `as` syntax you tell typescript to *treat* it like another type - it does not change the type of the object itself.

On how to convert an XML entity to a JavaScript Object look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object). 
Once you have a JavaScript Object you can use the `as` syntax to tell TypeScript to treat it as a `Request`.

An example of this (using [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)):

```
import {xml2js} from 'xml-js' 
// or with require:
// const xml2js = require('xml-js').xml2js;

enum status {
    Pending = 1,
    Rejected = 5,
    Validated = 6
}
interface Request { // Using interface instead of type
    totalInDays: number;
    status: status; // I think you had a mistake here in your question - should be of type 'status' not 'string'    
}

const response = '<ns1:Request> 
    <ns1:totalInDays>0.5</ns1:totalInDays>
    <ns1:status>1</ns1:durationInDays>
    <ns1:startDate>22/07/2019</ns1:startDate>
    <ns1:endDate>22/07/2019</ns1:endDate>
</ns1:Request>'


const object:Response = xml2js(response) as Response; // as Response might not be needed depending on the libraries typings, if there are any
```