# Nested Array with objects return specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I read an XML file:

This is the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RadanCompoundDocument xmlns="http://www.radan.com/ns/rcd">
  <RadanAttributes>
    <Group class="system" name="File" desc="These attributes are basic properties of the file." ord="1">
      <Attr num="101" name="Created" desc="Time file was created." type="t" ord="3" value="2021-05-04T09:39:19+02:00">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="102" name="Modified" desc="Time file was last modified." type="t" ord="4" value="2021-05-04T09:39:19+02:00">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="103" name="File size" desc="File size in bytes." type="i" ord="5" value="17832">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="105" name="Associated files" desc="Associated files." type="s" ord="6">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="107" name="Extension" desc="File name extension." type="s" ord="2" value="sym">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="110" name="File name" desc="File name without its extension." type="s" ord="1" value="RingAlu3mm">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="141" name="Checkout user" desc="The username to which this file is checked out" type="s" ord="7">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="142" name="Checkout time" desc="The time at which this file was checked out" type="t" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="143" name="Filestore" desc="Radcontrol local filestore path" type="s" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="h" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="144" name="Current version" desc='A flag to show (when set to "yes") that this is the current version of a file' type="s" ord="10">
        <Valid perm="r" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Description" desc="Use these attributes to give a description of the file." ord="2">
      <Attr num="108" name="Title" desc="The title of this file." type="s" ord="1">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="109" name="Comments" desc="Comments about this file." type="s" ord="2">
        <Valid perm="e" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    <Group class="custom" name="Manufacturing" desc="These attributes are the manufacturing properties of the file." ord="6">
      <Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1" value="AlMg3 H111">
        <Valid perm="e" max="20" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="120" name="Thickness" desc="Thickness." type="r" ord="2" value="3">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="121" name="Thickness units" desc="Thickness units." type="s" ord="4" value="mm">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="mm|in|swg" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="122" name="Orientation" desc="Allowed nest orientations (1=0°, 2=90°, 3=0/90°, 5=0/180°, 6=90/270°, 7=0/90/180/270°, 8=any)." type="i" ord="6" value="1">
        <Valid perm="e" min="1" max="8" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="123" name="Cycle time" desc="Cycle time in minutes." type="r" ord="24">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="127" name="Machine" desc="Machine name." type="s" ord="18">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="132" name="Mirror" desc="Whether the part can be mirrored in nesting." type="s" ord="7">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="139" name="STL id" desc="Standard Tool Loading file id." type="i" ord="19" value="23">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99" />
        <MC machine="psys_LES_4" value="23" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="145" name="Common cutting" desc="Whether the part is suitable for common line cutting in nesting." type="s" ord="8">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="none|unrestricted|same part" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="146" name="Strategy" desc="Autotooling strategy." type="s" ord="20" value="Nitrogen">
        <Valid perm="e" max="60" />
        <MC machine="psys_LES_4" value="Nitrogen" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="160" name="Picking cluster" desc="Whether to nest the part in clusters that are suitable for a part picker." type="s" ord="9">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="164" name="Weight" desc="The weight of the part in lb or kg, depending on the geometry units attribute value." type="r" ord="5" value="0.01923785677">
        <Valid perm="e" min="0" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="181" name="Maximum CC group" desc="The maximum number of parts in a common cut group." type="i" ord="10">
        <Valid perm="e" min="2" max="999999" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="186" name="Workflow status" desc="The workflow status of this file." type="s" ord="27" value="1 - OK">
        <Valid perm="e" max="80" />
        <MC machine="psys_LES_4" value="1 - OK" />
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="196" name="Kit of parts" desc="Symbol is a kit of parts." type="s" ord="11">
        <Valid perm="e" expr="yes|no" max="80" />
      </Attr>
    </Group>
    </Group>
  </RadanAttributes>
</RadanCompoundDocument>
```

I want to get the value of the object with name="Strategy"
so I do this:

```
const xml = fs.readFileSync(path)
const result = {}
let symXML = ''
parser.parseString(xml, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('xml2js.parseString: Error occurred: ', err)
    } else {
        symXML = res
    }
})
const manufacturing = symXML.RadanCompoundDocument.RadanAttributes.Group.find(
    (el) => el.$.name === 'Manufacturing'
)
```

what gives me the manufacturing section as an object

```
{
  '$': {
    class: 'custom',
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    desc: 'These attributes are the manufacturing properties of the file.',
    ord: '6'
  },
  Attr: [
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object], MC: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object], MC: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object], MC: [Object] },
    { '$': [Object], Valid: [Object] }
  ]
}
```

inside the array Attr it looks like this:

```
{
  '$': {
    num: '165',
    name: 'Bounding box X',
    desc: "The maximum extent of the symbol's geometry in the X direction.",
    type: 'r',
    ord: '2',
    value: '75'
  },
  Valid: { '$': { perm: 'e', min: '0' } }
}
```

and its here that i need the value of property 'value'

This won't work:

```
const result = {}
result.Strategy = manufacturing.Attr.find((el) => el.$.name === 'Strategy').$.value
```

Why does Array.prototype.find().$.value not give me a result?

This works:

```
result.Strategy = manufacturing.Attr.find((el) => el.$.name === 'Strategy').$.value
result.Strategy = result.Strategy.$.value
```

But that's just not right.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you expand the `[Object]` in the `$` properties of the `Attr` array?

Comment: You had a solution in your question - why you feel "that's just not right"?

Comment: There's something missing from your question. What are you using to get from the XML shown to the object? Because the code you show doesn't make any sense; `let symXML = ''; const manufacturing = symXML.RadanCompoundDocument` would return undefined.

Comment: i've edited the question and added the part were i read the file and who is responsible for the structure.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I'm looking for a cleaner approach, i'm sure its possible just dont know how

Comment: Maybe if you use [another parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object)... But it seems the structure of the object you have after parsing the XML forces you to do what you feel that's just not right.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

> Array.prototype.find(), The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

> Array.prototype.filter()
> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

.filter returns a new array, so take the fist element [0], and then navigate in it as an object .$.value
so:

```
result.Strategy = manufacturing.Attr.filter((el) => el.$.name === 'Strategy')[0].$.value
```

Comment: Nice, good job! You can also accept your own answer now.