# Is there way to find sibling element values using a value of a particular element as input in xml using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

In below example I want to find the values of author, year & price using the value 'Harry potter' as my input in jquery

```
<bookstore>
     <book>
      <title>Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
     </book>
     <book>
      <title>Harry Potter</title>
      <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
     </book>
    </bookstore>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200913/xml-to-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways you can attack it. Easist way is to use jQuery to convert it to XML (if you did not have it in that format already). You can then loop over it and find the titles and filter on those that match the same text. After that you can get the book and loop over the children to get the properties you are after.

```js
const xmlString = `
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
`;

// convert the xml into an object
const doc = $($.parseXML(xmlString));

// find all the titles that match
const titles = doc.find('book title').filter((_, title) => title.textContent === 'Harry Potter');

const data = titles.get().map((title) => {
  const book = $(title).parent();
  return book.children().get().reduce((obj, elem) => ({...obj, [elem.tagName]: elem.textContent}), {});
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Powershell

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$books = $doc.Descendants("book")

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($book in $books)
{
   $title = $book.Element('title').Value
   $author = $book.Element('author').Value
   $year = $book.Element('year').Value
   $price = $book.Element('price').Value
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
      title=$title
      author=$author
      year=$year
      price=$price
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Results

```
title            author              year price
-----            ------              ---- -----
Everyday Italian Giada De Laurentiis 2005 30.00
Harry Potter     J K. Rowling        2005 29.99
```

Comment: Not sure ho this answer fits in with the tags....